How to go from time zone abbreviation, such as PST, to canonical expansion for the locale
Is there a method in the Java standard library, or in some package such as JodaTime, which can expand a time zone abbreviation such as PST to the full name of that time zone appropriate for the locale?  For example, PST can be either Asia/Manila, America/Los_Angeles, America/Vancouver, or many others depending on whether the user is in the Philippines, US, Canada, etc.  I know there's getAvailableIDs in either JDK or JodaTime, but both provide an exhaustive list and don't give any guidance on which to pick in the event the user just says PST.  Ideally there would be something that uses the Locale to pick the closest or most relevant time zone.
Edit: I need to check further, but the comment below from Anonymous was the answer I was looking for.  The following code behaves as I would like:
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.from(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("z", Locale.US).parse("MST"));
    System.out.println(zone.getId());

    zone = ZoneId.from(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("z", Locale.CANADA).parse("MST"));
    System.out.println(zone.getId());

result:
America/Denver
America/Edmonton

It doesn't work perfectly, such as Locale.CHINA and CST still gives America/Chicago instead of a time zone in China, but this is a lot closer than having to guess when we get an ambiguous time zone as input.

Some abbreviations are ambiguous - CST could be Central or China or Cuba Standard Time - how would you choose.

Seems like OP wants to guess based on user's location?

I don't think JodaTime or the JDK come with the necessary data to build that kind of mapping (mostly because it's very much "guesswork"). I wouldn't be surprised if some third party come up with something like that, but I don't know of one. Those abbreviations should really NEVER be used for any kind of software-to-software communication and only ever used to display a time to a user in a familiar way.

These abbreviated time zones are mostly used in an informal, sloppy way. For example, many people refer to Pacific Time as PST, when it should be PT. PT changes its offset from UTC twice a year, and is the civil clock time used in the relevant areas. On the other hand, PST refers specifically to Pacific Time during the winter half of the year, when Daylight Time is not used. During summer, it's PDT. But many people use "PST" even in the summer, which is wrong. Do you want to take the correct interpretation or the "popular" interpretation?

... and they shouldn't be used for input, either. Instead, ask the user for the timezone in the Asia/Manila, etc. format.

Is the abbreviation standalone or does it always come with date and time plus offset? One could use the offset to narrow down the resulting set of zone ids.

"PST" (or "CET", "CEST", "MEZ", "MESZ" and all the others) or not abbreviations of timezones, but names for time patterns used in a particular timezone. For some timezones, this three letter codes can be used as a synonym for the timezone name(s) (like IST for all timezones defined for India), in others not (Europe/London has GMT and BST …) – not to mention that these time names are locale dependent and not unique (as you showed for PST already). And using them inappropriately may cause havoc, too: think about 2024-10-23T11:06:23CET (with CET being "Central European Time" here) …

You can do it, and as others have said, you are likely to get a wrong result because such abbreviations are ambiguous. ZoneId .from(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("z").parse("PST")) .getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL_STANDALONE, loc) gives Pacific Time if loc is Locale.US and heure du Pacifique nord-américain if it‘s Locale.FRENCH.

There isn't even a way to do this as a human, why would there be a way to do this for Java?

"There isn't even a way to do this as a human, why would there be a way to do this for Java?"
I don't think that's entirely true - if I'm in Denver and I say "Mountain Time", it's almost certain I mean the time zone in Denver, not the time zone in Dawson Creek

Great.  How are you figuring out that the user is in Denver?

The 2-4 letter abbreviations of pseudo time zones (CST, IST, etc.) are not standardized, and are not unique/distinct. So you cannot logically go from IST to India Standard Time or Ireland Standard Time. Use real time zone names, in format of Continent/Region like Asia/Kolkata or Europe/Dublin.

I think them being in the US at all would be close enough to believe they probably mean MST -> America/Denver, whereas Canada would make America/Dawson_Creek or some other Canadian time zone more appealing.  Hence the question of if there's a way to do it using Locale from the original post.

Following your latest edit, it is indeed not perfect; here's another example: ZoneId.from(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("z", Locale.UK).parse("BST")) ==> Pacific/Bougainville instead of British Summer Time.

Fully agree it's not perfect, but the previous version we had was putting users in Dawson Creek when they put in MST, which for most of our users was much further from perfect.  It's not a case of just ask the user for more information, either, since in this use case they may be using our software to process raw text they have no control over.  Having some kind of systematic disambiguation is going to be a lot more useful for those corner cases than a system where we simply pick the first one returned by getAvailableIds().  I wonder if BST,UK->Bougainville counts as a bug in Java...

@John I know many living far from the US having their devices set to US locale. So no, from the locale we cannot establish that they are in USA. Also when I am abroad, I typically use the same locale as at home, not the locale corresponding to the place where I am.

No, there isn't a way to do this in the Java standard library. For example, the (old) java.util.TimeZone documentation explicitly states:

For compatibility with JDK 1.1.x, some other three-letter time zone
IDs (such as "PST", "CTT", "AST") are also supported. However, their
use is deprecated because the same abbreviation is often used for
multiple time zones (for example, "CST" could be U.S. "Central
Standard Time" and "China Standard Time"), and the Java platform can
then only recognize one of them.

And Timezone.getTimeZone(String) also says:

Note that the support of abbreviations is for JDK 1.1.x compatibility
only and full names should be used.

The (new) java.time.ZoneId does not support the ambiguous short zone IDs with ZoneId.of(String), only unambiguous short IDs are supported.
To be able to use the ambiguous short IDs, you need to use ZoneId.of(String, Map<String, String>) method, where the map provides the mapping between unsupported names and a supported name. For compatibility of the mappings offered in java.util.TimeZone, it defines ZoneId.SHORT_IDS with the mapping historically offered by Java. This map is not modifiable.
In other words, if you want locale-sensitive short IDs mapped, you'll need to provide said mapping yourself with a custom Map<String, String>.
